# Appending URL with query object

Tags: python, django

I'm querying a database for objects and passing it to my html file through my view.
The way I have my urls.py set up is such that `/index/object_primary_key` -
Therefore, each object in my database has its own URL.

This is the code I typed thinking it would work, but I now know the URL function doesn't work that way:

```
<a href="{% url 'index'%} {{object.pk}}">{{object.title}}</a>
```

Is there a way to use a query and append it to a url?

Comment: what is your index url patter ?

Comment: my index url pattern is /index/

Comment: what about this `/index/object_primary_key`? can you post your urls.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After setting up your url pattern correctly, the simpler way is:

```
{% url 'index' object.pk %}
```

But the most effective is [`get_absolute_url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method in your model class: *(In most cases, used because of slug in url)*

This tells Django how to calculate the canonical URL for an object. It returns a string that can be used to refer to the object over HTTP.

I suppose that you have your urls pattern set as the following

```
url(r'index/(?P<pk>\d+)',index,name='index')
```

The method will be:

```
from django.urls import reverse

class ModelClass(models.Model):
    ''' fields '''
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index', args=[str(self.pk)])
        # or with kwargs={'pk':str(self.pk)}
```

In your template, you may call it that way

```
<a href="{{object.get_absolute_url}}">See me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try     "{% url 'index' pk=object.pk %}"